# How to get correct output using mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql to generate correct output. I am join two table using left join with the where clause my both table structure is given below:

**I am using query**

```
select e.fee_particular,e.fee_amount,s.paid from es_feemaster e left join es_feepaid_new s on s.fee_particular=e.es_feemasterid where s.es_preadmissionid=914 and s.voucherid=208 and e.fee_class=13
```

My first table structure

[image]

My Second table structure is

[image]

[image]

I am getting this kind of output

[image]

But my desire output should be

[image]

Please help me to generate desire output as soon as possible.

Thanks  in advance

Answer (score 0):

Outer join is the solution i hope. same can be done with an NVL too.

```
select e.fee_particular,e.fee_amount,s.paid from es_feemaster e left join es_feepaid_new s on s.fee_particular=NVL(e.es_feemasterid,s.fee_particular) where s.es_preadmissionid=914 and s.voucherid=208 and e.fee_class=13
```

Comment: your query not working showing error FUNCTION acadtouch.NVL does not exist

Comment: NVL is oracle fn for NULL VALIDATION. May be a mysql replacement would fix it pal.

Comment: yes mysql has ifnull() function but output is not correct which required by me

Comment: Just use outer join. Thats enough i believe, forget about NULL checks.